# using React to show existing JS/html pages in Tabs

Tags: javascript, php, html, reactjs

I am new to React I am trying to create a simple code.
At the moment I have several dashboards that I wrote using HTML/JavaScript/JQuery integrating with a php server code in MVC way.

My goal is to create a dashboard center, basically this page will show a few Tabs, each tab will  load a different dashboard.

I run into multiple problems when importing my files (I added them to the src directory) when importing JS files to the react app, I get failed to compile on about everything inside those files.
the react is also shouting about me using ag-grid compoinents inside the JS files.

is there a way to do what I need to achieve ? 
is there a way to load a html files from within the React app.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Tabs from './Tabs';
require('./tab-dashboard-css/tabStyles.css');


function App() {
  return (
      <div>
        <h1>Tabs Demo</h1>
        <Tabs>
          <div label="Generic Dashboard">
              // I want to load an html file into a Tab like this
          </div>
          <div label="Test 1">
            After 'while, <em>Crocodile</em>!
          </div>
          <div label="Test 2">
            Nothing to see here, this tab is <em>extinct</em>!
          </div>
        </Tabs>
      </div>
  );
}


export default App;
```

this is an example of one of my html files

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Generic Dashboard</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/ag-grid-enterprise.min.noStyle.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css">
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <!--Bootstrap-->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/UI_Assets/select2/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="/UI_Assets/select2/select2.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
    <!--Page CSS-->
    <link href="/dashboards/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <!--Font - OpenSans -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="../js/AccountGenericsDashboard.js"></script>
    <title>Campaign/AdSet/Ad</title>
</head>
<body>
<!--FIRST BOX-->

<div class="container custom_container">
        <div id="Main" align="center">
            <h1><b>Generic Dashboard – Accounts</b></h1>
            <span class="card_label">Client:<br></span>
            <select class="SelectClientClass" id="SelectClient" onchange="handleClientSelection()">
                <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select Client / App</option>
            </select>
        </div>
</div>

<!--SECOND BOX-->
<div class="container custom_container2" id="freeGenericGridBox" align="center">
    <div id="freeGenericGrid" style="height: 320px;width:300px;" class="ag-theme-balham"></div>
</div>

<!--THIRD BOX-->
<div class="container custom_container3" align="center">
    <div id="usedGenericGrid" style="height: 600px;width:1300px;" class="ag-theme-balham"></div>
</div>

<!--FORTH BOX-->
<div class="container custom_container3" align="center">
    <div id="excludedFieldsGrid" style="height: 600px;width:1300px;" class="ag-theme-balham"></div>
</div>

</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#SelectClient").select2();

        $("#SelectClient").select2({ width: 400 });

        $("#SelectClient").change(function(){
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to render your app component into your `index.html` file. See these sample projects -https://reactjs.org/community/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `react` and `react-dom` depandencies and your building `app` into your html file.
Then you need the following code to render your App component:

```
ReactDom.render(React.createElement('App'), HTMLElement);
```

Comment: what do you mean by import ?
do I import them inside a html file ?
right now I used npm to build my react.

Comment: i mean, inject the script file into your html file

Answer (score 0):

Hi if anyone ever have a similar question.
in the end I solved the problem with using react-iframe

then my react app just loaded my previous JS/JQUERY pages from a link to my server.

when I develop new apps from now I will do it in react no problem.
this was an easy solution for integrating my previous dashboards inside a tab component in a react app.